# Low-latency audio playback for JS code in Android chrome

Tags: javascript, android, audio, low-latency

I am running a JS script in 5.1 android chrome (the latest update for my MOTO G) that has a significant latency ( probably over 200ms). The audio player is simply:

```
// some output to the screen //
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
function play(frequency, duration) 
{
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.value = frequency; // value in hertz
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);
oscillator.start();
setTimeout(function(){oscillator.stop();}, duration);   
}
```

Is it possible to improve this latency for the same smartphone and the same android version? I can accept around 100ms, and 50ms is good enough. Also latency in just the first call of the function is Ok.

Btw will such a code work well on an uptodate android smartphone or on an iphone?

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce the latency you will want to use a native solution. I recommend Superpowered for all audio processing. Otherwise you will deal with this every step of the way. On average, it's around 10ms delay for Android devices, and I can imagine your having to fight against server response too. Which in high performance audio apps is going to destroy you.

From my experiences with this exact same problem, we solved it successfully by accounting for MS delay per phone, then also allowing users to control the audible delay difference (which is hard for most).

Comment: Can you estimate how much latency can be shaved when moving from JS in Chrome to native app? For example if it's in the 20ms area then it's meaningless in my ~150ms latency device...

Comment: I recommend checking out Superpowered and their round trip latency detection app. It will help you get benchmarks, and they also have a great resource of collected data over thousands of phones. Hope it helps man, been down this rabbit hole before! 

https://superpowered.com/latency